# Vim - Shortcut To Go To NERDTree Without Resetting?

Tags: vim, macvim, nerdtree

I am new to vim, so if this is really stupid I apologize in advance, but I can't seem to find it on google.

I found on stack overflow this snipped which sets the focus to nerdtree:

```
let mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>ne :NERDTree<cr>
```

But if i have a bunch of directories expanded when I run this command it resets, is there a way where it does not reset?

I am using Macvim if it helps.

Also, I know about `:NERDTreeToggle`, but I want the tree visable all the time.

Comment: Try `:NERDTreeToggle` instead of `:NERDTree`.

Comment: @glts that hides the tree I want it open all the time

Comment: No, it doesn't hide the tree, it toggles it. Open, close, open, close, ... Actually I'm not sure what you're asking, can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? It is not clear from your question. What is the mapping supposed to do?

Comment: @glts I think he just wants to go to the window that NERDTree is in. So the answer I think @AriPorad wants is `<c-w>` with a direction `h`,`j`,`k`,or `l` to change the focus to a different window. (Or at least this is how I'm interpreting the question)

Comment: @FDinoff, thats what I want, but I do not know in advance how many buffers will be open

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to focus a particular window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127439/how-to-focus-a-particular-window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@FDinoff has shown the way, but actually you don't need to implement the NERDTree focus yourself. It's undocumented, but it's built in.

Try this mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>ne :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12127439) great answer by @kev.

Comment: This is what I get for looking at the documentation and not the source code

Comment: @FDinoff I know, it feels almost unfair, but I found it by browsing the Stackoverflow search ... upvote for effort, though :P

Answer (score 3):

The nerdtree window has the filetype of `nerdtree`

Below is a function that will focus the first window that has filetype nerd tree or leave the cursor in the window it was originally in.

```
function! FocusNERDtree()
    let initial_win_num = winnr()
    for i in range(1, winnr('$'))
        exec i.'wincmd w'
        if &filetype == 'nerdtree'
            return 1
        endif
    endfor
    exec initial_win_num.'wincmd w'
    return 0
endfunction
```

So you can just create a map for this.

```
nnoremap <leader>nf :call FocusNERDtree()<cr>
```

Or you could just move the window manually using `<c-w>` and a direction (`h`,`j`,`k` or `l`)